# Bypassing "Run-Time Error 1004" on corrupt file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop that opens a number of files from a list in a worksheet and then copies the data, some of the files have been deleted, but I can exclude these (runtime error 1004). However some of the files are corrupt and the error handler is crashing out. Same error, different reason. Any idea how I can exclude these also? The data in these are useless so needs to be skipped.

```
Sub EDITING LOOP()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Long

    With Workbooks("BOOK1.xlsb").Worksheets("SHEET1")

     For i = 2 To 29

        xfile = .Cells(i, 1)
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        Workbooks.Open (xfile)
        Application.Goto Reference:="TABLE1"
        Selection.copy
        ActiveWindow.Close

ErrHandler:

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then .Cells(i, 2) = "ERROR" Else .Cells(i, 2) = "OK"
        .Cells(i, 3) = Err.Number

Err.Clear      
' On Error Resume Next (TRIED BUT DIDN'T WORK) 
' On Error GoTo 0      (TRIED BUT DIDN'T WORK)

        Next

    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I suggest you read: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm Here your error block is executed even if you are no getting an error. I suggest you put your error catching outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is often better to encapsulate an error test in its own function.  In this way you can more easily separate the 'happy path' from the 'error path'.

```vb
Sub EDITINGLOOP()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim i As Long

    With Workbooks("BOOK1.xlsb").Worksheets("SHEET1")

        For i = 2 To 29

            xfile = .Cells(i, 1)
            Dim myErrorNUmber As Long
            Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
            If Not TryOpenFile(xfile, myErrorNUmber, myWorkbook) Then

                .Cells(i, 2) = "ERROR"
                .Cells(i, 3) = myErrorNumber

            Else

                .Cells(i, 2) = "OK"
                Application.GoTo Reference:="TABLE1"
                Selection.Copy
                ActiveWindow.Close

            End If

        Next

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Public Function TryOpenFile(ByVal ipFileName As String, ByRef opErrorNum As Long, ByRef opWorkBook As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set opWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(xfile)
    opErrorNum = Err.Number
    TryOpenFile = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

You will notice that the tryOpenFile function return the error number and a reference to the workbook if it was successfully opened.  Your current code seems to make some unwqarrented assumtions about the active worksheet after the open worksheet function.  I haven't tried to correct your code.

The use of On Error Resume Next to manage testing for error conditions is discussed in more detail here  https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/05/

Comment: Thanks for your work on this. I have given it a try but I get an invalid or unqualified function. I don't quite understand that function. Perhaps an easier way to look at it is if I have a list of files in column a, using the i loop how can I check that these files are valid

Comment: Use a filesystem object so that you can test to see if each file exists (using the exists method).  Your list of names in excel can be loaded into a VBA array so you should be able to do a for each loop over the filenames.